# declare set from the same table in sql 2005

Tags: sql

For each row in the table SalesRep_Info, i have a column ManagerID. ManagerID is the primary key of the same table having the ManagerID saved for each Sales Rep. So i  need to get the FirstName of the Manager as a new column. I am wondering if this is the right way of doing it in sql server 2005 by declaring and setting?!!

Thank you in advance!

```
declare @RepID int

set @RepID = (Select Manager from SalesRep_Info)

Select *, (Select FirstName from SalesRep_Info where RepID=@RepID) as ManagerFname from SalesRep_Info
```

Comment: This will display errors - did you read the errors and understand them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a join:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.FirstName AS ManagerFirstName
FROM
    SalesRep_Info a
    LEFT JOIN SalesRep_Info b ON a.ManagerID = b.RepID
```

Comment: Thank you! I dint know Join can be used for the same table. Learnt something new :-)

Comment: It can be, but you need to make sure that each table name is unique - thus the renaming of the table to a and b.  You could also have just renamed the second one to SalesRep_Info2 or whatever your preference is.  To be clearer, you could do something like FROM SalesRep_Info SalesRep LEFT JOIN SalesRep_Info Manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @RepID int //ok

set @RepID = (Select Manager from SalesRep_Info)   // error - it must have 1 value. you should use top 1.
```

*Select top 1 Manager from SalesRep_Info*

what does it mean `Select top 1 Manager from SalesRep_Info` ??

where is the `where` clause ? is the manager is the same one for everyone?

finally :

```
Select *, (Select FirstName from SalesRep_Info where RepID=@RepID) as ManagerFname from SalesRep_Info
```

this will throw error too.
the second argument also must return 1 value.

Comment: Manager is not the same for everyone. Managers are also in the same table but Sales Rep have an ManagerID column with one of the Manager! I need to get all the SalesReps with their Manager's Name and also Managers in the same stored proc! Thank you!